# Group by date from timestamp in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm adding exact timestamp to every document. I need to display number of documents received according to date.

I tied

```
{$group: {_id: '$timestamp' }},function(err,docs){}
```

But as the timestamp also includes time, each document is getting in different group.

How do I group those docs by Date/Month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
Used date aggregation operators.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/

```
DataStream.aggregate(
    {$group:
    {_id: {$hour:'$at'},
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }},function(err,docs)
    {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        res.json(docs);
    });
```